# Unhandled Exception iOS 12.5.5 when running Flutter on physical device using XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to run a Flutter app using XCode on a physical device but it seems that the current device version `12.5.5` is not supported.

I created a 12.5 version from the 12.4 version folder that I found in DeviceSupport, restarted XCode, but it displays the same error.

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.5`

```
Unhandled Exception: SignInWithAppleNotSupportedException(Unsupported platform version: iOS 12.5.5)
#0      MethodChannelSignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential (package:sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface/method_channel_sign_in_with_apple.dart:86:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Apple Login is only supported from version 13 and on.